# Добавить свои стили в Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

Всем привет есть такой фрэйм

```
<iframe src="https://kurs.kz/informers/informer_frame_3.php" width="300" height="455" frameborder="no" scrolling="no">

</iframe>
```

Все классно, размещаю на сайте, работает, хочу кое какие стили подправить, но не получается, потому что во фрэйм открывается и закрываются теги `head` и `body`. Как внутри своего сайта добавить стили для этих элементов?

Comment: или спарсить эту страницу и оформить уже у себя как угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Надо добавить стили ВНУТРИ того документа, который открывается в ифрейме. По умолчанию доступа внутрь ифрейма с родительской страницы нет.

2) Доступ к содержимому ифрейма расписан тут: https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/29376-dostup-k-soderzhimomu-iframe.html